# How to preview Custom Font Android Studio (using Calligraphy)

Tags: android, android-layout, preview, android-library

Currently I'm using the Calligraphy library to use custom fonts, it's awesome https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

But i can't preview the new fonts, is there any way to preview the custom fonts in Android Studio?

Comment: for preview you have to run the program and check on device or emulator

Comment: That is quite the opposite of previewing...

Answer (score 0):

In order to view the Custom fonts you have to run the code and check in the mobile.
**Note :**ALL Fonts may not be accurate in emulator,Better to run in mobile for best experiance.

Comment: In latest android studio you can directly double click on font in assets folder and preview the font.Hope it was helpful for you.